# Has anyone encountered and resolved - org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: uniqueContextId not found

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am getting following error during test execution:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: uniqueContextId not found

The script is trying to find following element

```
//html[contains(@class,'act')]/body[contains(@class, 'pace-done') and contains(@class, 'SKINNED')]
```

when this error is encountered.
The Xpath is to find an element with class "SKINNED pace-done", but it is split because the classname may have leading, tailing or in between spaces.
Has anyone encountered "uniqueContextId not found" issue?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue for the first time today. In my case, the issue was that the WebDriver was focused on an iframe> that had just loaded a new page. Apparently this affected the "uniqueContextId" in the v8 inspector.

The issue was 100% reproducible for me when running locally and not in headless mode, but tended to work fine when run headless on our CI server.

[Following the suggestion in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75385830/219710), I was able to solve the issue by slowing down the test when the InvalidArgumentException happens:

```java
private static void tolerateWebDriverSyncIssue(Runnable reRunnableTask) {
    InvalidArgumentException failures = null;
    for (int attempt = 1; attempt <= 2; attempt++) {
        try {
            reRunnableTask.run();
            return;
        } catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
            if (failures == null) {
                failures = e;
            } else {
                failures.addSuppressed(e);
            }

            // give Chrome time to catch up before retry
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
    throw failures;
}
```

I wrapped my failing lookup via `tolerateWebDriverSyncIssue(() -> webDriver.findElement(By ...))` and it now succeeds on the second try.